# how to handle, in one html file, parallel view of the same document in different languages?

Tags: html, css

I need to display in parallel the same document in 2 different languages but I'm having problems adjusting the same heights because some paragraphs are longer in one language than in the other. how can I do it without creating specific ids for each paragraph? thanks in advance!

I have tried setting max-width and also dividing the text into smaller boxes but I actually have no idea how to solve this.

this is a fragment of the code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #left{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;    
}
#right{
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
</style>

<body>
<section id="left" lang="eng">
<h1>title</h1>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
</section>
<section id="right" lang="hr">
<h1>title in croatian</h1>
<div>same text but in croatian</div>
<div>text in croatian</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Put the elements in a grid, and have it flow in columns with the height of each row defined as min-content.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content min-content min-content ;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
```

```html
<main>
    <h1 lang="en">Example</h1>
    <p lang="en">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
    <p>Donec finibus ipsum non mi bibendum sodales. Curabitur eu convallis sem. Nulla vestibulum mollis dui. Phasellus tincidunt pellentesque magna a mollis. Quisque semper tellus non felis posuere fringilla ac eget lorem. Nunc enim eros, tristique nec gravida at, gravida consectetur dolor. Aliquam sollicitudin massa odio, sit amet placerat nisi imperdiet non. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut elementum, nulla vitae ultricies ullamcorper, arcu nunc egestas nunc, eget bibendum nulla libero sit amet neque.</p>
    <p lang="en">Finished.</p>
    <h1 lang="fr">Exemple</h1>
    <p lang="fr">Le renard brun rapide saute par-dessus le chien paresseux.</p>
        <p>Donec finibus ipsum non mi bibendum sodales. Curabitur eu convallis sem. Nulla vestibulum mollis dui. Phasellus tincidunt pellentesque magna a mollis. Quisque semper tellus non felis posuere fringilla ac eget lorem. Nunc enim eros, tristique nec gravida at, gravida consectetur dolor. Aliquam sollicitudin massa odio, sit amet placerat nisi imperdiet non. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut elementum, nulla vitae ultricies ullamcorper, arcu nunc egestas nunc, eget bibendum nulla libero sit amet neque.</p>
    <p lang="fr">Finie</p>
</main>
```

Comment: it works if I have no more than 4 elements for each document (because of grid-template-rows), but my documents have several hundred paragraphs... Is there a way to use grid without stating the number of rows (grid-template-rows: min-content)? thanks anyway for your help!